# IValueConverter to Name for Generic Objects or String for strings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `ListBox` named **ListBoxView** which contains collection of objects. The ListBox is linked to `CollectionViewSource` for filtering the typed input from User.

I would like to show the **Name** property of the object in the `ListBox` when its a list of generic object, and when the `ListBox` contains list of strings, I would like to show them as strings. So I used `IValueConverter` to do this. But I am failing in using it.

Here below is the code for what I tried:

> WPF

```xml
<ListBox Grid.Row="2"
         Name="BoxList"
         FontFamily="Lucida Sans"
         FontWeight="Light"
         FontSize="13"
         Margin="5"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
         SelectionChanged="BoxList_SelectionChanged"
         SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content = "{Binding ElementName=BoxList,
                                          Path=ItemsSource,
                                          Converter={StaticResource PropertyValuNameConverter},
                                          ConverterParameter=Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

> C#

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var name = string.Empty;
    //Check if the value is a collection and proceed
    if (value.GetType().Name == typeof(List<>).Name)
    {
        foreach (var item in (IList)value)
        {
            if (item.GetType() != typeof(string))
            {
                var prop = item.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
                var val = prop.GetValue(value, null);
                name = val.ToString();
            }
            else
                name = item.ToString();
        }

        return name;
    }

    return "Not Converted";
}
```

The `ListBox` is showing everything with the same name, in this example my list contains `{a,b,c,d,e,f,j,k}` but it show als as `k`.

[image]

After many attempts and many searches online I couldn't figure out where it went wrong. I am no programmer please help me understand how to solve this or where I could refer for help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are iterating through all items, your converter will always return the `ToString()` representation of the last one.

Instead of binding to the `ItemsSource`, you could bind to the current item and check the type of this one:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var currentItem = value;
    var name = "Not Converted";

    if (currentItem.GetType() != typeof(string))
    {
        var prop = currentItem.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
        var val = prop.GetValue(currentItem, null);
        name = val.ToString();
    }
    else
        name = currentItem.ToString();

    return name;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ContentPresenter Content = "{Binding Path=.,
    Converter={StaticResource PropertyValuNameConverter},
    ConverterParameter=Name}"/>
```

Comment: it works flawlessly. Thanks a lot. A small question though how did it take the current item, by assigning the value to `var currentItem = value`? or by binding the `Path =.` to nothing . Could you care to explain me please ?

Comment: @Watarap: The dot in the path represents the current item in the `ListBox` so you bind to this one.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks once again.